# I have a shiny app that uses mlogit package but the created models dont work when i change variables

Tags: r, shiny, mlogit

I created a shiny app which uses the mlogit package,

in the shiny app, people can create there own models with different 
variables/ attributes

But when i change the attributes in the shiny app, the app crashes

This is the code:

The ui Part

```
   selectInput("B1V1","Variable 1:", c("All", unique(as.character(b1v1)))),
```

The server Part

```
   b1v1 <- c(names(Quebec))
   x <- as.numeric(input$B1V1)

   hsmarketshare <- apply(predict(mlogit(choice ~ x, Quebec, reflevel = "gg"), Quebec, outcome=F),2,mean)


    output$modelcalcmarketshare <- renderTable(hsmarketshare)
```

My error message

```
Warning in observeEventHandler(...) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Comment: `hsmarketshare` needs to be put in a `reactive()` function. Make sure to change the last line to `output$modelcalcmarketshare <- renderTable(hsmarketshare())

Comment: `reactive( input$calcmodel,{
   
   b1v1 <- c(names(Quebec))
   x <- as.numeric(input$B1V1)
 
   
   hsmarketshare <- apply(predict(mlogit(choice ~ x, Quebec, reflevel = "gg"), 
 Quebec, outcome=F),2,mean)
   
   
    output$modelcalcmarketshare <- renderTable(hsmarketshare())
  })`    when i do this than i get annother error message : `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: The line `output$modelcalcmarketshare <- renderTable(hsmarketshare())` does not belong within the reactive function. Also, you need to assign the reactive object to `hsmarketshare`. Instead you just stored it within a reactive object that you're not assigning to anything. In order to properly help you, it would be helpful to provide a fully reproducible example, and it may also be worth reading over the first few chapters of this book: https://mastering-shiny.org/

Comment: hi i put the whole code in the last answer